# PHP: как результат работы одного класса передать в другой?

Tags: php, классы, объекты, переменные, область-видимости

Только начинаю осваивать ООП. Программа у меня делится на несколько классов, экземпляры которых я вызываю в index.php:

```
require_once('Parser.php');

require_once('Controller.php')

$obj = new Parser();

$obj->getMyInformation();

$obj2 = new Controller();

$obj2->putInformationInTables();
```

Я хочу, чтобы "выходы" одного класса служили "входными данными" для обработки в другом. Так, как мне лучше передать информацию из класса Parser() в класс Controller()?

Может быть, самый оптимальный способ через аргументы классов? Попробовал так:

```
$obj2 = new Controller(30);

$obj2 = new Controller(40);
```

Но значения 30 и 40 не присваиваются никаким переменным внутри класса Controller().

Прочитал, что для этого используются статические переменные, конструктор... Но написано непонятно... Не смог повторить это у себя в коде... Подскажите, пожалуйста, как такие вещи правильно делаются?

Непонятно, как заставить экземпляры классов и классы координироваться...

Comment: и что вам мешает присвоить эти значения, раз они не присваиваются, а вам это надо ?

Comment: Я думал, это как с функцией. При Controller(40), значение 40 будет присвоено первой переменной в class Controller () { public $a, $b}

Comment: То есть, в данном случае, $a будет равно 40

Comment: Чувствую, вопрос тупой, но, честно, не врубился после прочтения теории

Comment: как класс должен узнать что именно $a = 40 а не $b ?

Comment: А где теорию осваиваете?

Comment: смотрите в магический метод __construct для классов

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, тут читаю:  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: @Valentin ну так вам надо читать и читать)) до конструкторов ещё не дошли

Comment: Это я на общую страницу ссылку скинул, а про __constructor, читал... Попробую по другим источникам лучше понять.. Спасибо за наводку! Что именно этот элемент решает мою проблему..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Я думал, это как с функцией. При Controller(40), значение 40 будет присвоено первой переменной в `class Controller () { public $a, $b}`

само по себе ничего никуда не запишется. создание нового экземпляра класса `new Classname()`  - это вызов функции-конструктора с указанными аргументами. Классический путь:

```
class Test {
    public $a;
    public __construct($a){
        $this->a = $a
    }
}
```

То есть вы объявляете класс, описываете переменные-члены класса. Описываете параметры конструктора, явно берете эти параметры и сохраняете значения.

В пхп 8 появился некий "синтаксический сахар", где эту рутинную операцию можно сократить до

```
 class Test {
     public __construct(public $a){}
 }
```

Таким образом, эти два фрагмента кода эквивалентны. Код становится короче, правда, появляется вопрос о наглядности. Ибо по сути не все члены класса перечислены в его декларации, так что, честно сказать, нововведение несколько спорное.

Comment: "рутинную операцию можно сократить" --- ужааааасная фича)) не смог устоять не написать))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да я тоже не осилил на кой это добавили.